# Rails and sass/css when does the generation occur (the css from the sass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

I have two files .sass and .css

I edit the sass and the css gets generated.

When does this happen?

I am using rails.  Is the rails server doing this or the web server?

Does it compare the dates of the 2 files and see if a new generation is needed?

Does it do it every time for requests that use the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running sass --watch, it happens everytime you save...

Comment: sure.  Can you tell me what process does it then, is there a background process always running on my machine for this?

Comment: When I do it I go to the directory I want to compile and I do 'sass --watch .:<where I want the output files to go>'. The process runs until I ctrl-C to kill it and it compiles on every save. If you're seeing compilation w/o running this I have no idea how it's happening.